# Running an office add-in failing on Office.onReady

Tags: javascript, node.js, office-js, office-addins

I'm running an Excel add-in on a local machine using node.js and it all works.

When publishing the add-in on a server, the following piece of code is not being executed:

```
Office.onReady(info => {
  if (info.host === Office.HostType.Excel) {
    document.getElementById("sideload-msg").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("app-body").style.display = "flex";
    document.getElementById("run").onclick = run;
  }
});
```

It seems the `Office.onReady` waits until the JS APIs are called which never happens.

Is this related with node.js installation on the server or what else could the issue be?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your question. Would you help to confirm if you are meeting the below exception as descripted in [Initialize with Office.onReady()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/initialize-add-in)

> However, there are exceptions to this practice. For example, suppose
> you want to open your add-in in a browser (instead of sideload it in
> an Office application) in order to debug your UI with browser tools.
> Since Office.js won't load in the browser, onReady won't run and the
> $(document).ready won't run if it's called inside the Office onReady.

Comment: Please use QUOTE for quote not `Code`